# Missing UriCodec class

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am confused with this,as I am using `android.net.Uri` class in a piece of code added, but my problem is that inside this `Uri` class there is an unresolved class `UriCodec`which is inside package `libcore.net.UriCodec`that is also unresolved,following is the snapshot.

[image: view of class]

```
 if ((url != null) && url.contains("?code=")) { 
// some other code
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                Log.i("", "CODE : " +  uri.getQueryParameter("code"));
}
```

I have also cleaned and rebuilt the project but no luck. After googling I came across this link [UriCodec class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+log/android-cts-4.1_r2/luni/src/main/java/libcore/net/UriCodec.java), but all this really messing up can any one guide me or explain why is this so. Or i'm missing anything.How to resolve this through a simple jar download instead of git

Comment: this class is not part of Android SDK. To use it you will have to use the jar or something that provides it.

Comment: @VladMatvienko  thnx for ur reply, i have a query i really dun know its a stupid one or logical, but I'm going ahead...I am confused how this class got compiled with a missing classes?